# Coupled 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say if I have a 2nd order coupled differential equation like this:

$$x''(t)+x'(t)-y'(t)=0\\
y''(t)-x'(t)+y'(t)=0$$
can I simply express it as:
$$x'(t)+x(t)-y(t)=0 \\
y'(t)+x(t)-y(t)=0$$
so I can solve it like it's a 1st order differential equation?
if not how do I go about solving this?

Comment: You signs are inconsistent.

Comment: Alternatively use new letters, it is usually a bad idea to directly re-purpose existing variable names. Set $u=x'$ and $v=y'$.

Comment: Meant to say your signs are inconsistent. Sorry for the typo :D.

Answer (score 1):

$$x'(t)+x(t)-y(t)=0$$
$$y'(t)+x(t)-y(t)=0$$

Should have been$$x'(t)+x(t)-y(t)=C_1$$
$$y'(t)+x(t)-y(t)=C_2$$
The constants of integration are not necessarily $0$

Comment: Sorry did not see your same earlier  answer. Shall delete.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Add both differential equations to get

$$x’’+y’’=0\implies (x+y)’’ = 0 \implies (x+y)’ = c_1 $$
$$\implies x+y = c_1t+ c_0$$

Use the last equation to eliminate $x$ in the initial differential equation and determine $y(t)$.

Comment: Or, for symmetry, use in the same way the difference of the equations, $(x-y)''=-2(x'-y')$.